# base64 decoding gives wrong characters in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, base64

```
/*javascript*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".information").each(function() {
        var encodedString = $(this).text();
        $(this).html($.base64.atob(encodedString, true));
    });
});

/*html*/
<div class="information">
    dGhpcyBpcyB0ZXN0IHN0cmluZw==
</div> 

/*javascript source*/
http://yckart.github.io/jquery.base64.js/
```

I am trying to decode this base64 encoded string, expecting the result
"this is test string". 
The library used is jquery.base64.js. It is not giving me the correct results.
But if I change it to

```
$(this).html($.base64.atob("dGhpcyBpcyB0ZXN0IHN0cmluZw==", true));
```

I get the successfully decoded "this is test string". I console logged $(this).text(); and it is exactly the same as "dGhpcyBpcyB0ZXN0IHN0cmluZw==".

Comment: I just tried it and it works; using https://github.com/yckart/jquery.base64.js/ and jQuery 2.1.1

Comment: I just tried it as well, and it failed. I am getting "ï¿ï¿ï¿ï¿ï¿ï¿ï¿ï¿ï¿ѡ¥́¥́ѕÍЁÍÑɥ¹ï¿ï¿ï¿ï¿ï¿ï¿ï¿ï¿". I am using JSP though, does that make any difference?